# BigQuery standard SQL - DELETE over multiple tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I can do a select query like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM
  `test.test_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX in('aaa', 'bbb')
```

But i cant do the same with DELETE.
I get "DML over table test.test_* is not supported for the following query:

```
DELETE FROM
  `test.test_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX in('aaa', 'bbb') and id = '111'
```

Is there a way to do delete over multiple tables?

Comment: This should be of some help - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with it.
It doesn't mention deleting from multiple tables.

Answer (score 4):

BigQuery doesn't support DML over wildcard tables.