# Standard-SQL: How to delete rows from multiple tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have several days of data in Google Big query. From each day i would like to delete event of a given name.

I tried:

```
DELETE FROM `my_data.events_201812*` 
WHERE
_table_suffix between '18' and '31' and
event_name = 'error'
```

However, i am getting:

```
DML over table my_data.events_201812* is not supported
```

Is there a convenient way of deleting rows across multiple dates in google big query?

This: [Does BigQuery support UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT (SQL DML) statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922795/does-bigquery-support-update-delete-and-insert-sql-dml-statements)

doesn't answer my question. The question is not if it is possible to delete the rows. It is possible, i know that. I am asking about a good way of deleting from a range of tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163234/bigquery-standard-sql-delete-over-multiple-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163234/bigquery-standard-sql-delete-over-multiple-tables) Note, DML operations with wildcard expansion is not a great way to work. It's good to be explicit than be sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does BigQuery support UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT (SQL DML) statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922795/does-bigquery-support-update-delete-and-insert-sql-dml-statements)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I know it supports these statements.It has been a feature since like 2016. I just don't know how to delete in a reasonable way from 30 tables at once.

Comment: Hi, okay, that is more like a duplicate. However, the answer is over 2 years old. In case i can't use the table range, what would be a good way to go around it?

Comment: And over 2 years, this stance has not changed. You will have to write physical DELETE statements in order to delete tables in Cloud BQ.

Comment: Ofcourse, you can parameterize this block via loop and delete in bash which in turn will issue respective DELETE statements everytime the variable expansion takes place.